# ionic-native-transitions not working, no animation

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I've implemented (or at least, I've tried) [ionic-native-transitions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ionic-native-transitions) into my app. When I run the app in the browser by using `ionic serve` I get the message in to console reading

> nativepagetransitions is disabled or nativepagetransitions plugin is
>   not present

Which is great, it won't work in my browser since it's a Cordova plugin, but it does prove that it's installed correctly. I've included it in my app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ionic', 'ngCordova', 'ionic-native-transitions']);
```

And as far as the documentation goes, that's readlly all that's necesary. However when I run the app on a device, there's no animations whatsoever. Is there anything I missed?

**Edit**

This is then how I transition to different states, expecting it to work:

```
$stage.go('someState');
```

Comment: Could you please show your code?

Comment: Besides adding 'ionic-native-transitions' as a dependency on your module and then using $state.go(). That's it as far as code goes.

Comment: add this line after your  $state.go() ,
       window.plugins.nativepagetransitions.slide({
                'direction': 'left'
            });

Comment: lets chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95655/discussion-between-muhsin-and-dean-gibson

Comment: You can not test native transition in browser instead use device/emulator.